# why this thread is not safe

Tags: java, multithreading

**Example One**:

```
public class Test { 
        public static void main(String[] args) { 
                ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2); 
                Runnable t1 = new MyRunnable("A", 2000); 
                Runnable t2 = new MyRunnable("B", 3600); 
                Runnable t3 = new MyRunnable("C", 2700); 
                Runnable t4 = new MyRunnable("D", 600); 
                Runnable t5 = new MyRunnable("E", 1300); 
                Runnable t6 = new MyRunnable("F", 800); 

                pool.execute(t1); 
                pool.execute(t2); 
                pool.execute(t3); 
                pool.execute(t4); 
                pool.execute(t5); 
                pool.execute(t6); 

                pool.shutdown(); 
        } 
} 

class MyRunnable implements Runnable { 
        private static AtomicLong aLong = new AtomicLong(10000);   
        private String name;             
        private int x;                       

        MyRunnable(String name, int x) { 
                this.name = name; 
                this.x = x; 
        } 

        public void run() { 
                System.out.println(name + " excute" + x + "，money：" + aLong.addAndGet(x)); 
        } 
}
```

this thread is not safe in this sample.

**Example Two**

```
public class CountingFactorizer implements Servlet { 
    private final AtomicLong count = new AtomicLong(0); 

    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) { 
        count.incrementAndGet(); 
    } 
}
```

why is this thread safe? somebody can tell me?

I'm study thread in java, but cannot understand two sample. Are they different?

Comment: why do you think example 1 is not threadsafe?

Comment: @dkatzel, you can run it in eclipse, most time it is right. **But**  it is not safe sometime.

Comment: not safe how?  just because it executes in a different order doesn't mean it's not threadsafe

Comment: @dkatzel,   oh, yes,  **in a different order** , I understand it suddently

Answer (score 1):

As far I can see both are thread safe. In both examples the static, class level, member is `AtomicLong` that is thread safe by definition. All other members in the first example are instance level member and are executed in different threads, so no conflicts at all.